# Select Earliest Invoice Date and Max Distribution Line Amount per Supplier

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using Oracle, PSQL, I am trying to figure out the earliest invoice date for each supplier. That would be simple enough, but I am also trying to figure out the max distribution line on the earliest invoice so I can determine what segment of the business the invoice belongs to. Segment is determined by SEGMENT_NUMBER in the example below. I know a sub query or multiple sub queries are needed here with a group by clause but I am at a loss. The syntax below is not even close, but I wanted to provided something for feedback.

```
SELECT 

       SUPPLIER_ID,
       INVOICE_NUMBER,
       SEGMENT_NUMBER,
       MIN(INVOICE_DATE) as EARLIEST_INV_DATE,
       MAX(DISTRIBUTION_AMOUNT) as MAX_DIST_LINE

  FROM INVOICE_DIST
```

Comment: Thanks for editing Craig. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Use Analytical function like `RANK()`.

```
SELECT SUPPLIER_ID,
       INVOICE_NUMBER,
       SEGMENT_NUMBER,
       INVOICE_DATE,DISTRIBUTION_AMOUNT
       (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID,
       INVOICE_NUMBER,
       SEGMENT_NUMBER,
       INVOICE_DATE,DISTRIBUTION_AMOUNT,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SUPPLIER_ID ORDER BY INVOICE_DATE,DISTRIBUTION_AMOUNT DESC) POSITION  FROM INVOICE_DIST) TBL WHERE POSITION=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I keep getting an ORA-00936: missing expression error

Comment: Yes sir. Apologies for not coming back to it sooner.

Comment: Trying to bump this - I have managed to get the POSITION but I cannot seem to include a where statement which causes only the first position to be selected.